# Show that $p \ \equiv \ 1\ (mod \ \ 4)$ and $(r/p)^2 + (t/p)^2 \equiv 0 \ (mod \ \ n/p^2)$

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

> Suppose $r^2 + \ t^2 \equiv \ 0\  (mod \ \ n)$, where $n$ is a positive integer, and suppose $p$ is an odd prime dividing $n$. Show that:
> a) if $p$ divides neither $r$ nor $t$, then $p \ \equiv \ 1\  (mod \ \  4)$;
> b) if $p$ divides one of $r$ or $t$, then it divides the other, and moreover, $p^2$ divides $n$, and $(r/p)^2 + (t/p)^2 \equiv 0 \ (mod \ \  n/p^2)$

For question a), my answer was "$p$ is an odd prime and $n$ is divisible by $r^2 + t^2$ then $p \ \equiv \ 1 \ (mod \ \ 4)$", but I think I was wrong.
For question b), I have no clue how to answer this.

I would be so thankful for your support to solve this problem !

Comment: I'm stumped on $1)$, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

$b)$ $(p|n$ so $p|r^{2} +t^{2}$ and $p|r(\implies p|r^{2})) \implies p|t^{2} \implies p|t$ therefore $p^{2} |r^{2},t^{2},n$.

From the problem statement, $r^{2}+t^{2} =nk$ and since $p^{2} |r^{2},t^{2},n$:

$\frac {r^{2}}{p^{2}}, \frac {t^{2}}{p^{2}}, \frac {n}{p^{2}} = (\frac{r}{p})^{2}, (\frac {t}{p})^{2}, \frac {n}{p^{2}}$ respectively, are all integers.

Hence, $r^{2}+t^{2} =nk \implies \frac {r^{2}}{p^{2}}+ \frac {t^{2}}{p^{2}}=\frac {n}{p^{2}}k$ so that $ (\frac{r}{p})^{2}+ (\frac {t}{p})^{2}\equiv 0 \pmod {\frac{n}{p^{2}}}$.